# Rails 3 routes with non-numeric id's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have an object that by necessity has an id that looks something like "1.3.6.1.4.1.25623.1.0.14377".  When I try to create a link that uses the id (such as `link_to my_object(object.id)`), Rails 3 barfs and says that no route exists.

I have verified that I have a valid route in place by trying `link_to my_object(1)`.  Rails doesn't have a problem with creating this link.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your routes.rb file look like?

Comment: It just has a simple resources statement (`resources :nvts`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've figured it out... By default, Rails freaks when a period (.) is found in a parameter field (in this case id).  To change this behavior, simply add a :constraints directive to your route statement and tell it explicitly what the parameter should look like.  In my case it turned out that the following fixed the problem:

```
resources :nvts, :constraints => { :id => /[0-9\.]+/ }
```

Thanks to [Avdi Grimm](http://avdi.org/devblog/2010/06/18/rails-3-resource-routes-with-dots-or-how-to-make-a-ruby-developer-go-a-little-bit-insane/) for his most helpful blog post.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should override in your model the method `to_param`, Rails uses it to generate id for routing.
Usually it looks like this:

```
def to_param
  object.parameterize
end
```

It gets the model's name and use as id in route.

Comment: Sorry to say that that didn't work... Rails still throws `ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :id=>"1.3.6.1.4.1.25623.1.0.18413", :controller=>"nvts"}):` when I `link_to "Show", nvt_path(nvt.id)`.  `link_to "Show", nvt_path(1)` renders what I expect.

Comment: This method should be in model class. By doing this you're overriding  method from ActiveRecord::Base. Then check in rails console: your_object.to_param => should return the name of your model.

Comment: my_object.to_param returns the ID as expected.  Rails is still throwing the same error.  My object is not a descendant of ActiveModel::Base.  Is that a problem?

Comment: Every model should be derived from ActiveRecord::Base to keep this data in DB. Try scaffolding for generating models.

Comment: The data is not stored in the database.  It comes from another source (an API to another software system). Do you think that the fact that it's a plain ol' object is what is causing Rails to barf?